# SQL Server CTE Running balance

Tags: sql-server

**#table1**

```
idno | amount
-------------
1    | 700
2    | 500
```

**#table2**

```
idno | amount1 | amount2 | amount3 | acctno
------------------------------------------
1    | 100     | 200     | 300     | 001
1    | 100     | 200     | 300     | 002
2    | 100     | 200     | 300     | 001
```

What I want to happen is to distribute the amount from table2 into table 1's amount1,amount2,amount3 respectively then get the remaining balance and apply to the next row. I've tried using CTE but got stucked on passing the running balance to the next row.

**Query:**

```
Declare @table2 TABLE (idno varchar(max), amount1 decimal,amount2 
decimal,amount3 decimal,acctno varchar(max))
INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES
('1',100,200,300,'001'),
('1',100,200,300,'002'),
('2',100,200,300,'001')
Declare @table1 TABLE (idno varchar(max), amount decimal)
INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES
('1',700),
('2',500);
WITH due AS (SELECT a.idno,a.amount,b.acctno,b.amount1,b.amount2,b.amount3
              from @table1 a left join @table2 b on a.idno = b.idno),
      payment AS (SELECT *,case when amount-amount1<0 then amount 
              else amount1 end as amount1pay
              ,case when amount-amount1<=0 then 0 
              when amount-amount1-amount2 <0 then amount-amount1
              else amount2 end as amount2pay ,
              case when amount-amount1-amount2<=0 then 0 
              when amount-amount1-amount2-amount3<0 
              then amount-amount1-amount2 else amount3 end as amount3pay
              FROM due),
      payment2 AS (SELECT SUM(amount-amount1pay-amount2pay-amount3pay) 
                   OVER ( PARTITION BY idno ORDER BY acctno
             ROWS  UNBOUNDED PRECEDING  ) as balance,* FROM payment)

select * from payment2
```

**Current Result**

```
balance | idno | amount | acctno | amount1 | amount2 | amount3 | amount1pay | amount2pay | amount3pay
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  100   |    1 |    200 |   001  |     100 |     200 |    300  |    100     |    200     |    300
  200   |    1 |    200 |   002  |     100 |     200 |    300  |    100     |    200     |    300
    0   |    2 |    500 |   001  |     100 |     200 |    300  |    100     |    200     |    200
```

**Expected Result**

```
balance | idno | amount | acctno | amount1 | amount2 | amount3 | amount1pay | amount2pay | amount3pay
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  100   |    1 |    200 |   001  |     100 |     200 |    300  |    100     |    200     |    300
  100   |    1 |    200 |   002  |     100 |     200 |    300  |    100     |      0     |      0
    0   |    2 |    500 |   001  |     100 |     200 |    300  |    100     |    200     |    200
```

Comment: It is currently *very* unclear what the rules you are trying to apply here are.  Please add more detail on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

This seems very messy, as there's a lot of different things going on here.  I don't think I quite understand all of the "rules" for how you are distributing this money but this query does produce the expected results (actually it's slightly different, but I think you have a mistake in your table where you show "200" for amount in the first two rows it should be "700")?

```
WITH Base AS (
    SELECT
        t1.idno,
        t2.acctno,
        t1.amount,
        t2.amount1,
        t2.amount2,
        t2.amount3,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.idno, t2.acctno) AS row_id
    FROM
        @table1 t1
        INNER JOIN @table2 t2 ON t1.idno = t2.idno),
RunningBalance AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE WHEN amount > amount1 + amount2 + amount3 THEN amount - amount1 - amount2 - amount3 ELSE 0 END AS new_balance
    FROM
        Base),
NewIdno AS (
    SELECT
        idno,
        MIN(row_id) AS first_row_id
    FROM
        Base
    GROUP BY
        idno),
NewBalance AS (
    SELECT
        n.first_row_id AS row_id,
        b.amount
    FROM
        NewIdno n
        INNER JOIN Base b ON b.row_id = n.first_row_id),
Amount1 AS (
    SELECT
        b.row_id,
        rb1.new_balance AS balance,
        b.idno,
        b.amount,
        b.acctno,
        b.amount1,
        b.amount2,
        b.amount3,
        CASE WHEN ISNULL(n.amount, rb2.new_balance) >= b.amount1 THEN b.amount1 ELSE b.amount1 - ISNULL(n.amount, rb2.new_balance) END AS pay_amount1,
        ISNULL(n.amount, rb2.new_balance) - b.amount1 AS carried_forward_1
    FROM
        Base b
        INNER JOIN RunningBalance rb1 ON rb1.row_id = b.row_id
        LEFT JOIN RunningBalance rb2 ON rb2.row_id = b.row_id - 1
        LEFT JOIN NewBalance n ON n.row_id = b.row_id),
Amount2 AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE WHEN carried_forward_1 >= amount2 THEN amount2 ELSE carried_forward_1 END AS pay_amount2,
        carried_forward_1 - CASE WHEN carried_forward_1 >= amount2 THEN amount2 ELSE carried_forward_1 END AS carried_forward_2
    FROM
        Amount1),
Amount3 AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE WHEN carried_forward_2 >= amount3 THEN amount3 ELSE carried_forward_2 END AS pay_amount3
FROM
        Amount2)
SELECT
    balance,
    idno,
    amount,
    acctno,
    amount1,
    amount2,
    amount3,
    pay_amount1,
    pay_amount2,
    pay_amount3
FROM
    Amount3;
```

My results are:

```
balance idno    amount  acctno  amount1 amount2 amount3 pay_amount1 pay_amount2 pay_amount3
100     1       700     001     100     200     300     100         200         300
100     1       700     002     100     200     300     100         0           0
0       2       500     001     100     200     300     100         200         200
```

Some of the rules I am using:

- you start with the amount from table 1 to be distributed, i.e. £700    for idno #1 and £500 for idno #2;
- this is assigned to table 2 by acctnos in numerical order;
- where there are multiple acctnos you need to carry forward the balance from the previous one, if there's anything left to pay out;
- once you start a new idno you can't carry forward any money left from the previous one.

---

So how does it work?

Step 1 - Order the data and add an index (row_id)

This is just the base data from the two tables, showing how much we have to distribute and the rows we are distributing it over:

```
idno    acctno  amount  amount1 amount2 amount3 row_id
1   001 700 100 200 300 1
1   002 700 100 200 300 2
2   001 500 100 200 300 3
```

Step 2 - Work out the running balance

This works out how much money is left if we distributed the entire amount available across each row:

```
idno    acctno  amount  amount1 amount2 amount3 row_id  new_balance
1   001 700 100 200 300 1   100
1   002 700 100 200 300 2   100
2   001 500 100 200 300 3   0
```

Step 3 - (Interlude) We need to know which row we will be distributing data over first

This is just the first row_id for each idno:

```
idno    first_row_id
1   1
2   3
```

Step 4 - Slightly wasteful, as we could have done this in the last step

We just need the total to be distributed over each "first" row:

```
row_id  amount
1   700
3   500
```

Step 5 - This is where we deal with the running balance properly

For each row the rule is that we start with the "new balance" which only exists for the first row of each amount to be distributed.  If this isn't the first row then we use the running balance instead, but we take this from the previous row (rb2.row_id = b.row_id - 1).  We will always have one or the other of these:

```
row_id  balance idno    amount  acctno  amount1 amount2 amount3 pay_amount1 carried_forward_1
1   100 1   700 001 100 200 300 100 600
2   100 1   700 002 100 200 300 100 0
3   0   2   500 001 100 200 300 100 400
```

So the carried forward isn't what is to be carried to the next row, it's what is to be carried to the next amount (amount 2 in this case) to be distributed.

Note that this works for your dataset, but it wouldn't work if there were more than two rows per idno.  If you were to have more than two rows per idno then you would simply need to add another stage to handle this scenario.

Step 6 - Carry Forward

For each amount we need to take it off the amount carried forward from the previous calculation, giving us the amount we can allocate to this amount, and the amount to be carried forward to the next calculation (which is redundant for amount 3 as there is no amount 4).

Comment: Hi Sir, I edited your carried_forward_1 a bit and I think carried_forward_3 should be using amount3 instead of amount2. I got satisfied with the results though can you please explain to me how did you pass the carried_forward_3 value to the next row?

Comment: Yes, that last carried_forward_3 calculation was incorrect, but it's also redundant, as we don't need to carry the third value anywhere, I'll remove it.  I'll also add an edit explaining how this script works in more detail.

Comment: Hi Sir, as you noted, I needed to consider having more than two rows per idno. Could you please show me how to do it or at least give me a hint?

Comment: The extra stage would work out the running balance for each row, possibly using a recursive CTE, or using a windowed function (which is how your original script worked), I will have an attempt at this when I get a chance, but unfortunately I am very busy today.